# Как вытащить значение из класса

Tags: java, android

Как получить значение из класса к примеру

Вот нужно чтобы root получило значение из oncreate

```
public class Inform extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA = "extra";
    String root = syb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String extra = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA);

        syb = extra;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите в строке `String syb = "12";` слово `String`.
А вообще вам нужно там написать

```
root = "12";
```

А в "верху" `String root = "" ;` например.

Comment: не выходит горит красным, сейчас код обновлю

Comment: @Артем сообщение ошибки компиляции тогда выложите.

Comment: вот так написал изменил выше

Comment: @Артем точное сообщение что пишет компилятор.

Comment: [вот пише ссылка и](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392750/uses-or-overrides-a-deprecated-api-compiler-warning):app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: @Артем, вы присваиваете переменно root несуществующий sib

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я вроде бы 2 строки посоветовал изменить.

Comment: спасибо все понял